# Are there queue and stack collections in Rust?

Tags: rust

If we need FIFO or LIFO collections (with basically `push`, `pop` and `front`/`back`) what should we use in Rust? Something like `std::queue` or `std::stack` from C++.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

First of all, Rust does not offer (in the Standard library) any collection with guaranteed latency for *adding* elements: Rust collections may generally allocate memory when adding new elements, and allocating memory may take an unbounded amount of time in the worst case.

That being said, there are two contenders for each case:

- a stack may be implemented either on top of `Vec` or `LinkedList` (both feature `pop_back` and `push_back`)
- a queue may be implemented either on top of `VecDeque` or `LinkedList` (both feature `pop_front` and `push_back`)

The difference between `Vec*` and `LinkedList` is that the latter is simplistic: for each call to `push_back` a memory allocation is made. On the one hand, this is great because it means that the cost of `push_back` is independent of the number of elements already in the collection, on the other hand... well, a memory allocation may take a really long time.

The former is a bit more complicated:

- it has better throughput, thanks to being more cache-friendly
- it has additional capacity, guaranteeing non-allocating `push_back` as long as there is excess capacity
- it still maintains *amortized* O(1) `push_back` even when not reserving excess capacity ahead of time

In general, I would advise to use `Vec` for a stack and `VecDeque` for a queue.

Comment: can't `VecDeque` be used as a stack too ?

Comment: @Nulik: By the law of "who can the most, can the least", yes. However, since `VecDeque` supports additional functionality, it is not as lean as a `Vec` which may lead to performance overhead when used as a `Vec`, thus my advice.

Comment: How does one ever have "guaranteed latency"?

Comment: @Fermi-4: Short of an RTOS on a real-time processor? Never in theory. Practically speaking, though, even on Linux you can achieve fairly low bounds by using OS facilities to give a thread exclusive access to a core -- as long as you avoid calls to the OS, and I/O. In this particular case, the things to watch out for are (1) memory allocation (unbounded in time) and (2) re-allocation of buffers (linear in time).

Answer (score 25):

Both [`VecDeque`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.VecDeque.html) and [`LinkedList`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.LinkedList.html) have `push`/`pop`_`front`/`back`.

Comment: Humm thanks, I searched for the magic keywords `FIFO` and `LIFO` and had nothing significant. Maybe it is a documentation problem.

Comment: I saw std::Vec is a good choice for a stack, but what is the more efficient for a queue?

Comment: It depends on your use case.  I would guess that `LinkedList` would be more predictable, but `VecDeque` on average more efficient in some ways, but really you'd have to measure it yourself.

Comment: @Boiethios: use the mentioned `VecDeque` for queues. `LinkedList` is O(1) on the front, but not at the back, so it is more appropriate for a stack.

Comment: LInkedList is O(1) to push/pop to either end.

Comment: A `LinkedList` is a pretty terrible stack, `Vec` is virtually always faster. Same goes for `LinkedList` vs. `VecDeque` as queue.

Answer (score 23):

Matthieu M. has it just about perfect.  [`Vec`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html) is your stack (LIFO) and [`VecDeque`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/struct.VecDeque.html) is a double ended queue that supports all 4 variants (FIFO, FILO, LIFO, and LILO) using:

```
.push_front(x) | .front() | .pop_front()
.push_back(x)  | .back()  | .pop_back()
```

If you're looking to maximize your efficiency, I recommend checking out ["Unterstanding  Rust’s Vec and its capacity for fast and efficient programs"](https://web.archive.org/web/20201030081237/https://markusjais.com/unterstanding-rusts-vec-and-its-capacity-for-fast-and-efficient-programs/). It goes into a lot more detail about how allocation and reallocation occurs in `Vec` and `VecDeque`, but the biggest take away is that if you can predict the maximum number of elements you're going to need in the queue you can use `VecDeque::with_capacity(x)` if you know when you initialize it, or `.reserve_exact(x)` if at some point you know exactly how many *more* slots you're going to need

I strongly recommend checking out the Rust docs on [`std::collections`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/index.html), it has an excellent list of the most common collections used in Rust, along with suggestions on when to pick each

One last thing, `VecDeque` isn't part of the default prelude in Rust so if you want to use it you need to include this:

```
use std::collections::VecDeque;
```

Comment: Note: Link is dead, use archived version: https://web.archive.org/web/20201030081237/https://markusjais.com/unterstanding-rusts-vec-and-its-capacity-for-fast-and-efficient-programs/

Answer (score -3):

There is an crate [Queue](https://docs.rs/queues/latest/queues/) that implements queue.

Comment: This crate is very old, and also poorly implemented. I don't recommend it.